# Flutter: ListView cuts off BoxShadow as soon as elements overflow available space

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have an issue:
As soon as I add an element that overflows the length of the list view, the whole list view gets cut off at the sides. This is only visible because of the box shadow.

The following to pictures demonstrate the issue, the first with the working box shadows, and the second with the shadows cut off, as soon as there are to many elements.

[image: first picture]

[image: second picture]

Comment: Reproducing the problem requires the code that makes up this view , and  result of flutter doctor -v